# Configuring MostAllocated on an EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kube-scheduler

We would like to pack as many pods into each nodes in our cluster as much as possible do decrease the amount of nodes we have on some of our environments. I saw https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler HighNodeUtilization strategy which seems to fit the bill for what we need. However, it seems the cluster needs to have the scoring strategy **MostAllocated** to work with this.

I believe that the kube-scheduler in EKS in inaccessible to be configured. How do I then configure the MostAllocated scoring strategy?

Better yet, how do I configure this automated packing of pods in as little nodes as possible in a cluster without the use of Descheduler?

Tried deploying the descheduler as is without the MostAllocated scoring strategy configured. Obviously did not provide the results expected.

Many of my digging online led to having to create a custom-scheduler, but I have found little/unclear resources to be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Eks does not provide the ability to override the default scheduler configuration, which means that actually configuring the `default-scheduler` profile with the `MostAllocated` scoring strategy is not an option.  However, you may run your own scheduler *alongside* the default scheduler, and [this one may be configured how you like](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/).  Once you create a custom scheduler, you can override *that* scheduler's configuration with the `MostAllocated` scoring strategy and then instruct your workloads to use that scheduler.

In order to run multiple schedulers, you have to set up several Kubernetes Objects.  These objects are documented in the guide linked above:

- ServiceAccount
- ClusterRoleBinding x2
- RoleBinding
- ConfigMap
- Deployment

The deployment will use the standard `kube-scheduler` image provided by Google, [unless you'd like to create your own](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYcL0Un1io0).  I wouldn't recommend it.

#### Major Note: Ensure your version of the kube-scheduler is the same version as the control plane.  This will not work otherwise.

In addition, ensure that your version of the `kube-scheduler` is compatible with the version of the configuration objects that you use to configure the scheduler profile.  `v1beta2` is safe for `v1.22.x` -> `v1.24.x` but only `v1beta3` or `v1` is safe for `v.1.25+`.

For example, here's a working version of a deployment manifest and config map that are used to create a custom scheduler compatible with `k8s` `v.1.22.x`.  Note you'll still have to create the other objects for this to work:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: custom-scheduler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: scheduler
        name: custom-scheduler
        tier: control-plane
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/kube-scheduler
        - --config=/etc/kubernetes/custom-scheduler/custom-scheduler-config.yaml
        env: []
        image: registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.22.16
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10259
            scheme: HTTPS
        name: custom-scheduler
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10259
            scheme: HTTPS
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/custom-scheduler
          name: custom-scheduler-config
      serviceAccountName: custom-scheduler
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: custom-scheduler-config
        name: custom-scheduler-config
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  custom-scheduler-config.yaml: |
    apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta2
    kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
    leaderElection:
        leaderElect: false
    profiles:
        - pluginConfig:
            - args:
                apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta2
                kind: NodeResourcesFitArgs
                scoringStrategy:
                    resources:
                        - name: cpu
                          weight: 1
                        - name: memory
                          weight: 1
                    type: MostAllocated
              name: NodeResourcesFit
          plugins:
            score:
                enabled:
                    - name: NodeResourcesFit
                      weight: 1
          schedulerName: custom-scheduler
metadata:
  name: custom-scheduler-config
  namespace: kube-system
```